# Using LWC base UI components in node.js

Tags: lightning-web-components, node.js

Followed https://lwc.dev/ and managed to get open source lwc running on node  js app I'm working on - Thats great !! 
I can now use SLDS styling and use the lwc features like @api, @track etc..

Can I use the lightning base ui components inside my desktop app? 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components

Is there a way to import the library to my node project and use any of the base built in components like I would do in Salesforce? eg. using lightning-card, lightning-button etc... without just apply the styling which seems viable but bit longer.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce currently does not expose any node module to allow you to import these base components in LWC open source outside salesforce orgs.

However salesforce has open sourced code for few of these base components. They can be explored in the repo [here](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc).You can manually port some from the repo to your project.

There is also [another](https://github.com/pmdartus/lwc-slds) project which shows how to use SLDS inside open source lwc which will help to import SLDS to your project with open source lwc.